# My project seems to be built but an error keeps occurring and I cant find out why

Tags: vb.net

I'm using Visual Basic and I keep getting

Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target E:\OS FINAL\OS FINAL\bin\Debug\OS FINAL.exe is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutPutPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

I need serious help with this, I cant even test my program which sucks :/

Comment: Does that file exist or not? Did you check that the OutPutPath and AssemblyName properties are set to the correct values?

Comment: This sounds like your anti-virus program is quarantining/deleting the executable.  Try disabling it.

Comment: We can't see your disk drive contents from here. First, does the file exist in the folder mentioned? Use Windows Explorer to find out. Second, does a build work without errors? A single error will cause the executable to not be created, and clearly you can't run an executable that does not exist in the first place. If the code won't compile, it won't build, and there is no program to test. If you don't get any errors during the build, then it may be your antivirus software that's the issue. Disable it or tell it to exclude the folder. This is basic debugging, which we can't do from here.